# how to start jenkins server from bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I want to start my jenkins serveur from a pull request. I have a problem to configure the bitbucket serveur. I don't want to use use a crontab.

Comment: Are you thinking of bitbucket.org or bitbucket server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a one solution. you can use a token for that :

1 - your jenkins serveur should be accessible over internet

2 - Add TOKEN_NAME in your jenkins job.

3 - bitbucket should call on url after each commit

url template :

https://user:password@jenkins.mycompany.org/job/job_name/build?token= TOKEN_NAME

in https://jenkins.mycompany.org/configureSecurity

disable CORS

hope this help